# Trigger on first attempt

Tags: apex, trigger

I am very new in coding. Just trying to understand . For this code, it was giving me error in for loop. Could anyone help me to understand what is wrong here.

```
trigger AccountonInsert on Contact (after insert) {
    List <Account> Acc = new List <Account>  

    for (Contact con : Trigger.new) {       // here is where I check if Contact that is being inserted meets the criteria
        if (con.Department = "abc") {
            Account newacnt = new Account ();           //instantiate the object to put values for future record

            newacnt.ShippingAddress = con.OtherAddress; // now map Contact fields to new Account object that is being created with this Contact 

            Acc.add(newacnt);
        }
    }

    try {
        insert Acc; 
    } catch (system.Dmlexception e) {
        system.debug (e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the error here ***verbatim***.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple problems.

Proper list construction looks like `new List<Account>()`, not `new List<Account>`. You also must terminate each line with a semicolon (`;`).

**Incorrect**

```
List <Account> Acc = new List <Account>
```

**Correct**

```
List<Account> Acc = new List<Account>();
```

---

The first thing that jumped out is that you're trying to do a comparison but actually doing an assignment within your `if` evaluation:

**Incorrect**

```
if (con.Department = "abc") {
```

**Correct**

```
if (con.Department == "abc") {
```

See also: **[Understanding Expression Operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm)**

> **Operator**
>   `=`
>
> **Syntax**
>   `x = y`
>
> **Description**
>   Assignment operator (Right associative). Assigns the value of y to the L-value x. Note that the data type of x must match the data type of y, and cannot be null.
>
> ---
>
> **Operator**
>   `==`
>
> **Syntax**
>   `x == y`
>
> **Description**
>   Equality operator. If the value of x equals the value of y, the expression evaluates to true. Otherwise, the expression evaluates to false.
>
> Note:
>
> - Unlike Java, == in Apex compares object value equality, not reference equality, except for user-defined types. Consequently:
>
>   - String comparison using == is case-insensitive
>   - ID comparison using == is case-sensitive, and does not distinguish between 15-character and 18-character formats
>   - User-defined types are compared by reference, which means that two objects are equal only if they reference the same location in memory. You can override this default comparison behavior by providing equals and hashCode methods in your class to compare object values instead.
> - For sObjects and sObject arrays, == performs a deep check of all sObject field values before returning its result. Likewise for collections and built-in Apex objects.
> - For records, every field must have the same value for == to evaluate to true.
>     x or y can be the literal null.
> - The comparison of any two values can never result in null.
> - SOQL and SOSL use = for their equality operator, and not ==. Although Apex and SOQL and SOSL are strongly linked, this unfortunate syntax discrepancy exists because most modern languages use = for assignment and == for equality. The designers of Apex deemed it more valuable to maintain this paradigm than to force developers to learn a new assignment operator. The result is that Apex developers must use == for equality tests in the main body of the Apex code, and = for equality in SOQL and SOSL queries.

Comment: Thank you, Learned new things. Still getting this error  Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'for'

Comment: This is why you should always include error message in your posts here...

Comment: Sorry, My mistake .

Comment: @SFlast, if the answer solves your purpose then accept that, so that others may find this useful